# Unable to filter using WHERE (Cannot access field hour on a value with type ARRAY<STRUCT<hitNumber INT64, time INT64, hour INT64)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, standards

```
#standardSQL
SELECT DISTINCT geoNetwork.country
FROM `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_*`
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20170701' AND '20170701' 
AND
hits.hour > '11'
```

I'm trying to view list of countries that sent hits to Google Analytics between 12 noon and midnight (in Standard SQL)
I'm using hits.hour from https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719?hl=en but get this error:
Cannot access field hour on a value with type ARRAY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#standardSQL
SELECT DISTINCT geoNetwork.country
FROM `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_*`
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20170701' AND '20170701' 
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST(hits) hit WHERE hit.hour > 11)
```

Comment: Hi Mikhail, another user [Gordon] also commented on this thread. I read about UNNEST function and kinda understand that it converts all the hits from the array into separte rows - which makes sense because GA session is made up of hits. In your answer, you have 'AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM...), can you please explain what this bit of the query does? THx

Comment: @AdilK - in my solution each row is evaluated on existence of hit with hour > 11. So each row is either survives or not based on that where clause and number of rows to be involved by DISTINCT is the same as original count of root rows . In Gordon's solution, all rows are cross joined on their respective hits and then rows with hour > 11 being involved into final DISTINCT. Of course the final result is the same but path to it is "shorter" with my solution

Comment: Thanks. Have a follow up question: I'm now trying to sum transactionRevenue...In one session, a user can have multiple sessions....in this case, why is the UNNEST opeprator not required?                                                                               
 SELECT 
SUM(totals.totalTransactionRevenue)
FROM `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_*` 
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20170701' AND '20170701';

Answer (score 2):

You can fix your syntax with:

```
SELECT DISTINCT geoNetwork.country
FROM `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_*`
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20170701' AND '20170701' AND
      hits[offset(0)].hour > 11
```

But that doesn't really do what you want.  Instead, you need `unnest()`, because `hits` is an array.  So:

```
SELECT DISTINCT geoNetwork.country
FROM `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_*`,
     unnest(hits) hit
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20170701' AND '20170701' and
      hit.hour > 11;
```

Also note that `hour` appears to be a number so the single quotes are inappropriate.